# Is Microsoft Remote Desktop.app on MacOS programmable?

Tags: macos, rdp

I use Mircosoft Remote Desktop app on my MacBook, is it programmable like using AxMstscLib DCOM on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,
there is nothing like AxMstscLib for programming from Microsoft on macOS,or you can try [FreeRdp](http://www.freerdp.com/) on mac.

---

btw, I make RDP/SSH management utility on Win that makes launching remote sessions very convenient and fast. Hope you can enjoy it and help to test it. Any of your advice or report is priceless .
https://github.com/VShawn/PRemoteM